# making a multiline, expanding TextInput with React-Native

Tags: ios, ios8, react-native

I'm working on a react-native app and need a TextInput that has similar functionality to the textview in the "messages" app on iOS—it should start out as one line and then gracefully expand to more lines until some limit (like 5 lines of text) and then start scrolling along to latest line as needed.

Took a look at the `SlackTextViewController` but a) seems like it has a lot of stuff that I don't want and b) I'd like to try to keep as much code in React (and out of objective-C/swift) as possible.

**Edit: Just want to emphasize that I would prefer REACT (JAVASCRIPT) code, as stated above, rather than Objective-C or Swift.**

Comment: Check this library out, it hasn't been updated for a while but it works pretty well. https://github.com/HansPinckaers/GrowingTextView

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I tried two different ways to do this today. Neither are the best but I thought I'd record my efforts in case they are helpful. They both definitely had the effect you are looking for, though sometime delayed with all the async communication.

## 1) Offscreen Text height

So just under the TextInput, I added a regular Text field with the same font and padding and such. I registered the `onChange` listener on the input and called `setState({text: event.nativeEvent.text})`. The Text filed got its value from the state. Both had `onLayout` Listeners. Basically, the goal was to get the height for the TextInput from the (unrestricted) Text. Then I hid the Text way offscreen

https://gist.github.com/bleonard/f7d748e89ad2a485ec34

## 2) Native Module

Really, I just needed the height of the content in the *real* UITextView. So I added a category to RCTUIManager as there are several methods there already that are helpful. I got rid of the hidden Text view. So `onChange`, I ask for the height and use that in the same way via the state.

https://gist.github.com/bleonard/6770fbfe0394a34c864b

## 3) Github PR

What I really hope is that this PR gets accepted. It looks to do something like this automatically.

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/1229

Comment: Can you make those gists public and not secret? Couldn't find them in your Gist profile :)

Comment: Update: Support for auto-resizing text fields has been added https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/481f560f64806ba3324cf722d6bf8c3f36ac74a5

Answer (score 15):

Adding `multiline={true}` to a TextInput will allow scrolling if the amount of text exceeds the available space. You can then change the height of the TextInput by accessing the nativeEvent.contentSize.height of the event from the onChange prop.

```
class Comment extends Component {
   state = {
      text: '',
      height: 25
   }

   onTextChange(event) {
     const { contentSize, text } = event.nativeEvent;

     this.setState({
        text: text,
        height: contentSize.height > 100 ? 100 : contentSize.height
     }); 
   }

   render() {
      return (
         <TextInput
            multiline
            style={{ height: this.state.height }}
            onChange={this.onTextChange.bind(this)}
            value={this.state.text}
         />
      );
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As of Oct'17 there is a nice component from Wix to do this:

https://github.com/wix/react-native-autogrow-textinput

The usage can be very simple:

```
<AutoGrowingTextInput
  style={styles.textInput}
  placeholder="Enter text"
  value={this.state.text}
  onChangeText={this._handleChangeText}
/>
```

And there are some extra props like `minHeight` and `maxHeight` for example.

I'm using it on RN 0.47.2

Comment: Still working today with { 
  "react-native": "0.62.2",
  "react-native-autogrow-input": "0.2.1",
}

Answer (score 3):

For anyone wants an easy solution, using new versions of RN, currently using 0.63.4,
the team added autoGrow to the TextInput if it's multiline, which is the case.

Don't use **height** (StyeSheet property) for the component or the parent View/Views

Use **minHeight**, **maxHeight** instead, and if multiline is enabled, the TextInput will grow till reaching the **maxHeight**, then will be scrollable.

no calculation nor inner state needs to ba maintained.

Same thing apply for **minWidth**, **maxWidth** if you need to expand widly.

Comment: maybe this works with iOS and not with Android (I'm testing it and it doesn't work on Android)

Answer (score 2):

Since `react-native-autogrow-textinput` seems to be unmaintained, I would recommend using native-base `<Input/>` as it has properties that enables multiline and auto-height as follows:

```
import { Input } from 'native-base'

<Input
    height={'auto'}
    multiline={true}
    // ...
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Implement the `UITextView`'s delegate method `textViewDidChange` and play with the rect

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView {
  CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(textView.frame.size.width, MAXFLOAT);
  CGRect textRect = [textView.text boundingRectWithSize:constraintSize
                                               options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                            attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:textView.font}
                                               context:nil];
  NSLog(@"Frame:%@", NSStringFromCGRect(textRect));
  CGRect newRect = textView.frame;
  newRect.size.height = textRect.size.height;
  textView.frame = newRect;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@Groovietunes got almost all of it correct but as of 26-06-19 things have change a bit from his initial answer.

For one, the `onChange` prop on textinputs no longer returns the `contentSize` object, hence `event.nativeEvent.contentSize` will return `undefined`.

The fix for this is to use the `onContentSizeChange` prop. But there's a catch; `onContentSizeChange` runs only once when the component mounts thus making it impossible to dynamically get the height as it changes.

To fix this we need to make sure the `value` prop is set after `onContentSizeChange` in the hierarchy of props in order to keep obtaining the content size as the `textinput` grows.

At the end of it all i had a component that looked like this

```
<TextInput
        placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
        autoFocus={this.props.autoFocus}
        style={[
          styles.inputFlat,
          { height: this.state.height > 40 ? this.state.height : 40 }
        ]}
        ref="inputFlat"
        onFocus={() => {
          this.toggleInput();
          this.toggleButton();
        }}
        multiline={this.props.multiline}
        onBlur={() => {
          this.toggleInput();
          this.toggleButton();
        }}
        onChangeText={this.props.onChangeText} 
        onContentSizeChange={event => {
          const { contentSize } = event.nativeEvent;
          this.setState({
            height: contentSize.height
          });
        }}
        value={this.state.value}
      />
```

if for some reason it seems broken as at the time of viewing this answer, refer to [this](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput#onchange) documentation for any updates

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to check `'\n'` symbols and set the `numberOfLines` property.
Works for me.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {TextInput} from 'react-native';

export default class TextInputAutogrow extends Component {

    constructor(props) {

        super(props);

        this._ref = null;

        this.bindRef = this.bindRef.bind(this);
        this.onChangeText = this.onChangeText.bind(this);

        this.state = {
            numberOfLines: this.getNumberOfLines()
        };
    }

    bindRef(c) {

        this._ref = c;

        this.props.innerRef && this.props.innerRef(c);
    }

    getText() {

        return typeof this.props.value === 'string' ?
            this.props.value :
            (
                typeof this.props.defaultValue === 'string' ?
                    this.props.defaultValue :
                    ''
            );
    }

    getNumberOfLines(value) {

        if (value === undefined) {

            value = this.getText();
        }

        return Math.max(this.props.numberOfLines, value.split('\n').length - 1) + 1;
    }

    onChangeText(value) {

        this.setState({numberOfLines: this.getNumberOfLines(value)})
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <TextInput
                {...this.props}
                ref={this.bindRef}
                numberOfLines={this.state.numberOfLines}
                onChangeText={this.onChangeText}
            />
        )
    }
}

TextInputAutogrow.propTypes = {
    ...TextInput.propTypes,
    innerRef: PropTypes.func,
};

TextInputAutogrow.defaultProps = {
    numberOfLines: 4,
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I found the code where you can set max and min height just like a chat textInput.
Check and let me know the same. 100% working without any glitch.

```js
import { useState } from 'react';
import { TextInput, ScrollView, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const GrowingTextInput = ({ style }) => {

  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('');
  const minHeight = 40;
  const maxHeight = 120;

  const calculateInputHeight = contentHeight => {
    const height = Math.min(maxHeight, Math.max(minHeight, contentHeight));
    return height;
  };

  const [inputHeight, setInputHeight] = useState(minHeight);

  return (
    <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
      <TextInput
        multiline
        value={inputValue}
        onChangeText={setInputValue}
        onContentSizeChange={event => {
          const height = calculateInputHeight(event.nativeEvent.contentSize.height);
          setInputHeight(height);
        }}
        style={[styles.input, { height: inputHeight }, style]}
        placeholder="Type here..."
      />
    </ScrollView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  input: {
    borderColor: 'gray',
    borderWidth: 1,
    fontSize: 16,
    padding: 10,
  },
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 20,
  },
});

export default GrowingTextInput;
```