# How would I grow <TextInput> height upon text wrapping?

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to create a `<TextInput>` that can grow in height when the text wraps to the next line, similar to how Slack's message input grows with the text up to a point.

[image: Slack input]

I have the `multiline` prop set, so it is wrapping but the docs don't seem to mention any event regarding wrapping, and the only thing I can think of is a really hacky strategy to character count to figure out when to increase height of the input. How would I accomplish this?
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [making a multiline, expanding TextInput with React-Native](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31475187/making-a-multiline-expanding-textinput-with-react-native)

Answer (score 80):

Thanks to react-native doc: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html

You can do something like that:

```js
class AutoExpandingTextInput extends React.Component {
  state: any;

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {text: '', height: 0};
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <TextInput
        {...this.props}
        multiline={true}
        onChange={(event) => {
          this.setState({
            text: event.nativeEvent.text,
            height: event.nativeEvent.contentSize.height,
          });
        }}
        style={[styles.default, {height: Math.max(35, this.state.height)}]}
        value={this.state.text}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

0.46.1 or higher: (as explained by Nicolas de Chevigné)

```js
class AutoExpandingTextInput extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {text: '', height: 0};
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <TextInput
        {...this.props}
        multiline={true}
        onChangeText={(text) => {
            this.setState({ text })
        }}
        onContentSizeChange={(event) => {
            this.setState({ height: event.nativeEvent.contentSize.height })
        }}
        style={[styles.default, {height: Math.max(35, this.state.height)}]}
        value={this.state.text}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This is nice answer. But my problem is : I have two text input field where I use above answer. When I type something in one text input field, then another is also grow at the same time. What can be done to fix this, so that only one text input is grow at a time ?

Comment: Are you using the same state value in both input ? like in `onChange` when you use `setState` create a unique key for each one, like `textUsername` and `heightUsername` and use it in the `value` props and in the style, do the same with the other input and this one would grow alone.

Comment: @Satan A little late, but you need to use AutoExpandingTextInput as it's own component and not plug this straight in to your current component.

Comment: When you delete lines it just won't shrink

Answer (score 46):

Since React Native [0.46.1](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.46.1) :

> *contentSize* property was removed from *TextInput.onChange* event

If you use this version, you can deal with `onContentSizeChange` prop

From [the Jérémy answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33071950/how-would-i-grow-textinput-height-upon-text-wrapping#37540479), we have

```js
function AutoExpandingTextInput(props) {
  const [text, setText] = useState('');
  const [height, setHeight] = useState(0);

  return (
    <TextInput
      {...props}
      multiline={true}
      onChangeText={(text) => setText(text)}
      onContentSizeChange={(event) =>
        setHeight(event.nativeEvent.contentSize.height)
      }
      style={[styles.default, { height: Math.max(35, height) }]}
      value={text}
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks!
But if I set up max height for my input

`onContentSizeChange={(event) => {
                let currentHeight = event.nativeEvent.contentSize.height;

                if (currentHeight > 100){
                  currentHeight = 100;
                }

                this.setState({
                  inputHeight: currentHeight
                })
              }}`


and I have a lot of text in it, it does not scroll to the bottom after height set up 100, how to slove this issue ?

Comment: On iphone all fine, but on android I have this issue.

Comment: I'm getting this to work when I hit <Enter>, but not when the line wraps.  contentSize.height is always 14 as long as I type a very long line that wraps several times; but as soon as I hit <Enter> for a new line, it increases to 28.  Only an <Enter> press will increase height, not wrapping.

Answer (score 38):

You should just set a `maxHeight` property in the `style`:

```
<TextInput multiline style={{maxHeight: 80}} />
```

Demo here: https://snack.expo.io/@yairopro/multiline-input-with-max-height

Comment: Does not work for Android where you need to use numberOfLines which change the default height (different behavior on android)

Answer (score 7):

My answer is to use `onContentSizeChange` and `numberOfLines` props in TextInput, of course turn on `multiline`, this is my solution:

```
let numOfLinesCompany = 0;
<TextInput
     ...
     multiline={true}
     numberOfLines={numOfLinesCompany}
     onContentSizeChange={(e) => {
         numOfLinesCompany = e.nativeEvent.contentSize.height / 18;
     }}
/>
```

18 is the height of text, propably depends on fontSize

Comment: How did you compute 18 as height for the font.

Comment: On `style` prop find the `fontSize` param

Comment: yes it's the font size

Answer (score 4):

Shoutout to [Jérémy Magrin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2310601/j%c3%a9r%c3%a9my-magrin) for his answer. This is his code but refactored to use functional components and hooks.

Note, you might need to use `minHight` instead of `height` in some RN versions.

```js
const AutoExpandingTextInput = ({...props})=> {
  const [text, setText] = useState('');
  const [height, setHeight] = useState();
  return (
    <TextInput
      {...props}
      multiline={true}
      onChangeText={text => {
        setText(text);
      }}
      onContentSizeChange={event => {
        setHeight(event.nativeEvent.contentSize.height);
      }}
      style={[styles.default, {height: height}]}
      value={text}
    />
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
<TextInput multiline style={{maxHeight: ...}} />
```

Answer (score 1):

In the hooks.

```
const [inputHeight, setInputHeight] = React.useState(40);

<TextInput
    multiline
    style={{ inputHeight }}
    onContentSizeChange={(event) => {
        setInputHeight(event.nativeEvent.contentSize.height);
    }}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

What I have done is set View for the Input max height, for example:

```
messageBox: {
maxHeight: 110,
width: '80%',
borderRadius: 10,
padding: 10,
backgroundColor: Color.White},
```

and set the Input to multiline:

```
<View style={[styles.messageBox, styles.managerMsg]}>
  <Input
    allowFontScaling={false}
    name="notes"
    blurOnSubmit={false}
    onChangeText={notes => console.log(notes)}
    returnKeyType="go"
    onSubmitEditing={() => Keyboard.dismiss()}
    multiline
  />
</View>
```

This "Input" is just a simple custom component that receives all Props.

Answer (score 0):

You might as well try something like this.

```
<TextInput style={[styles.inputs,{height: Math.max(35, this.state.height)}]}
                placeholder="Write a message..."
                multiline={true}                
                onChangeText={(msg) => this.setState({ text: msg })}
                onSubmitEditing={Keyboard.dismiss}
                onContentSizeChange = {() => this.scrollView.scrollToEnd({animated:true})}
               
              />
```

style.inputs

```
  inputs: {
    
    minHeight:40,
    marginLeft: 16,
    paddingTop: 10,
    overflow:'hidden',
    padding: 15,
    paddingRight: 25,
    borderBottomColor: '#000000',
    flex: 1,
    position: 'absolute',
    width: '100%',


  },
```

When the text grows beyond one line, a scroll view is created within the text input field and scrolls automatically to the bottom. This actually doesn't increase the text input height when the content grows, instead, a scroll view is created within the input field. Serves the purpose.
I'm posting my solution as others didn't work for me(the text input size grew behind the keyboard, and there were text-overflow issues).
Hence, for anyone who faced a similar problem as I did, this would hopefully work for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<View style={{flex:1}}>
    <TextInput
        multiline={true} />
</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use onChangeText to set the TextInput height like so.

```
  const textHeight = 19 //fontsize of the text
  <TextInput
  style={[styles.input, 
         {height:Math.max(40,inputHeight)}]}

  onChangeText= {text => {
    const height = text.split("\n").length
    setInputHeight(height * textHeight)
  }}

  multiline
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use multiline={true} no need to set height. check the following

```
<SafeAreaView style={{flex:1, backgroundColor:"#F8F8F9"}}>
        <ScrollView style={{flex:1}}>
            {
                this.state.data && <CommentListView data={this.state.data} onReplyClick={this.onReplyClick}/>
            }
        </ScrollView>
        <View style={{bottom:Platform.OS=="ios" ? this.state.keyboardHeight : 0, flexDirection:"row", alignItems:"flex-end", padding:10}}>
            <TextInput 
            multiline={true}
            style={{flex:3, backgroundColor:"#EFEFEF", borderRadius:5, padding:10}} 
            value={this.state.comment} 
            onChangeText={(text)=> this.setState({comment:text})}
            />
            <TouchableOpacity style={{flex:1}} onPress={()=> this.submit()}>
                <Text style={{padding:13, color:"#fff", textAlign:"center", fontWeight:"bold", backgroundColor:"#00394D", borderWidth:1, borderColor:"#00FFEE", borderRadius:5, overflow: "hidden"}}>Post</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
```

Comment: Unless this is included in a new release of React Native and I'm behind the times, I don't think this is correct. The [Docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#oncontentsizechange) don't hint at this being the case either. 

You need `onContentSizeChange` to adjust the size of the input field. Setting `multiline={true}` allows for linebreaks, but they will not change the size of the field.