# Auto growing text input with multiline in react native

Tags: react-native

I created a custom component which includes a TextInput and Icon inside a View. I want to grow my view height when the TextInput has multilines. This is my component. How can I achieve this?

```
import React from "react";
import { View, TextInput, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import { InputIcon } from "../";

const commentInput = props => (
  <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
    <TextInput
      {...props}
      underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
      style={[
        styles.input,
        { fontSize: props.fontSize },
        props.style,
        !props.valid && props.touched ? props.invalidInput : null
      ]}
    />
    <InputIcon
      name="upload"
      size={30}
      color="gray"
      onPress={props.onPress}
      disabled={props.disabled}
    />
  </View>
);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  inputContainer: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignSelf: "center",
    width: "96%",
    marginLeft: 2,
    marginRight: 2,
    marginBottom: 10,
    height: 50,
    borderRadius: 50,
    backgroundColor: "transparent",
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: "gray"
  },
  input: {
    width: "90%",
    textAlign: "center",
    color: "gray"
  },
  icon: {
    marginTop: 18,
    paddingRight: 5
  }
});
```

export default commentInput;

Comment: I think it may be duplicate anyways below link may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33071950/how-would-i-grow-textinput-height-upon-text-wrapping

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can combine `multiline` with `minHeight` prop to achieve this effect.

The relevant code would be

```
<TextInput
     multiline //... to enable multiline

<InputIcon
     style={{alignSelf: 'center'}} //... Should be self centered

inputContainer: {
        marginTop:100,
        flexDirection: "row",
        alignSelf: "center",
        width: "96%",
        marginLeft: 2,
        marginRight: 2,
        marginBottom: 10,
        minHeight: 50, //... For dynamic height
        borderRadius: 50,
        backgroundColor: "transparent",
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: "gray",
        paddingLeft: 10, //... With respect to the min height, so that it doesn't cut
        paddingTop: 10, //... With respect to the min height, so that it doesn't cut
        paddingBottom: 10 //... With respect to the min height, so that it doesn't cut
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

Your use case seems to be similar to any chat input field. The easiest solution would be to add `multiline=true` in TextInput field. I am assuming that you don't want to increase the height of your image. If you want to do it, then you can add an `onContentSizeChange` on the TextInput field and then update the height of imageView programmatically. 
You can refer to this very famous open source chat solution for sample code,
https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-gifted-chat/blob/master/src/InputToolbar.js