# How to make multiline property false on press of enter key?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I want the search bar to get empty on press of enter key and not to get multiline i.e making the multiline property false. But I also observed that to read enter key native event multiline property should be true.

```
handlePress=(e)=>{
        if(e.nativeEvent.key == "Enter"){
          this.setState({searchTerm:''});
        }
    }
render(){
        return(
          <View style={styles.container}>
              <FontAwesome name={'search'} style={styles.searchIcon}/>
              <TextInput
                  placeholder='Search...'
                  value = {this.state.searchTerm}
                  multiline={true}
                  style={styles.input}
                  onKeyPress={this.handlePress}
              />
          </View>
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What i can think of the solution is

```
state={
   multiLine: false
}

    handlePress=(e)=>{
        if(e.nativeEvent.key == "Enter"){
          this.setState({searchTerm:''});
        }
         this.setState({ multiLine:!this.state.multiLine })
    }
render(){
        return(
          <View style={styles.container}>
              <FontAwesome name={'search'} style={styles.searchIcon}/>
              <TextInput
                  placeholder='Search...'
                  value = {this.state.searchTerm}
                  multiline={ this.state.multiLine }
                  style={styles.input}
                  onKeyPress={this.handlePress}
              />
          </View>
        );
    }
```

So i have tried and not encountered any problem, there might be a possibility that some thing else in causing this problem, here is what i have done

```
<Input 
                placeholder = "Task"
                multiline={ this.state.multiLine }
                style= {{ marginTop:8 }}
                onChange= {e => this.setState({ task: e.nativeEvent.text })}
                value= {this.state.task}
            />
```

Comment: How is it messing up with CSS?

Comment: input:{
        fontFamily:"Times New Roman",
        fontSize:20,
        padding:12,
        marginTop:8,
        textAlign:'left',
    }

Comment: After it become false marginTop is kind of increasing

Comment: let me check once

Comment: please check if there is anyError in console

Comment: and also, thats the corerct line `this.setState({ multiLine:!this.state.multiLine })`

Comment: please check the edited answer, i have added my code, and it is working fine, without any margin issues

Comment: I think, what you are noticing is the height increasing and decreasing of `TextInput`

Comment: Yes the placeholder is shiftind down as soon as i hit enter

Comment: I think thats a normal behavior, because when `multiLine` is enabled it increases the height of text input, and when disabled it goes back to original state, and the place holder will shift down, its a native behavior as well, coming from native android development background I am sure this happens in native side as well.

Comment: So is there any other solution to the problem

Comment: As i said, i dont think it as a problem, it a natural behavior,

Comment: You can also try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37540479/7835745) , it may help you in solving your other problem, and do accept the answer as it solved the core problem you had in question, so it may help others in future