# How to make an automatic increase in the width of the text input field depending on the number of lines?

Tags: react-native

How to make an automatic increase in the width of the text input field depending on the number of lines? The multiline parameter did not help to enlarge the field itself, only added the ability to wrap text on a new line when the number of characters exceeds the width of the input field.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, TextInput } from 'react-native';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const TaskForm =() => {
    return(
        <MainView>
            <TextStyle>Название*</TextStyle>
            <InputWindow>
            <TextInput multiline={true}/>
            </InputWindow>
            <TextStyle>Описание</TextStyle>
            <InputWindow>
            <TextInput/>
            </InputWindow>
        </MainView>
    )
}

const MainView = styled.View`
    flex: 1;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 20px;
`;

const InputWindow = styled.View`
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #DCDCDC;
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    
`

const TextStyle = styled.Text`
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 600;
`;

export default TaskForm;
```

Comment: Here is the solution for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33071950/how-would-i-grow-textinput-height-upon-text-wrapping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
onLayout={(event) => {
                    if (textInputHeight === 0) {
                      setTextInputHeight(event.nativeEvent.layout.height);
                    }
                  }}
                  onContentSizeChange={(event) => {
                    setTextInputHeight(event.nativeEvent.contentSize.height);
                  }}
```