# TextInput with React Native displays a single line

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to implement two text inputs. I'm not sure if the best practice is to wrap these inside a scroll view or not. However, when I do it as shown below, I just see a single line in the middle.

If I remove the scroll view and just leave a single Text Input, it displays a box with input that I can interact with. Though I'm still unable to get the keyboard to display on the simulator. But I can manually type in and change state.

Any idea on how to allow more than one text input, as well as how to show the native keyboard that pops up from the bottom?

```
render() {
    return (
      <ScrollView>
      <TextInput
        style={{height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1}}
        placeholder="Enter item 1"
        value={this.state.text}
        onChangeText={this.onChange} />
        <TextInput
          style={{height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1}}
          placeholder="Enter item 2"
          value={this.state.text}
          onChangeText={this.onChange} />
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Are you on iOS ? There should be an option to toggle between Hardware keyboard-your PC- and the one shown on your screen. I think it's ⌘K on the iOS simulator. You can find it in the top menu otherwise iOS Simulator -> Hardware -> Connect hardware keyboard should be unchecked for the on-screen keyboard to show up.

Comment: Regarding your display problem, I can't try it on iOS-no Mac near me- but in Android seems to work just fine. Try adding styles to the attribute `contentContainerStyle` on your ScrollView ? Maybe using flex or setting height will resolve problem (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#content). Anyways, try using the Inspector to inspect elements on your screen (Menu -> inspector).

Answer (score 0):

1 - For the iOS Simulator there is an option Hardware -> Keyboard -> Toggle Software Keyboard (which is unchecked by default). Checking this option should solve your issue of displaying the native keyboard.

2 - Regarding multi-line text input. Yes this is an issue, but there is a work around shared in this answer below. I'll attach the link to the answer for your reference.

P.s: I haven't tried it myself, but the answer has been marked to have solved the issue!

[Multi-Line TextInput Hack - https://stackoverflow.com/a/31759113/5783646](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31759113/5783646)

Answer (score 0):

- Display keyboard in iOS Simulator: **Hardware -> Keyboard -> Toggle Software Keyboard**
- Show more than one text input: **My guess is that there are styles applied (or not applied) to a parent element or elsewhere that is preventing the TextInput from rendering at a useable size.**

I created an example on RN Playground that demonstrates what you are asking for: https://rnplay.org/apps/ldlfWw